# form keep on submitting onchange

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using this code to auto submit the form

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

the form contain an image file input, once the image is selected the function is called, and this function creates an image that is inserted to display as follow:

```
document.getElementById("uploadImage").onchange = function() {
var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.width = 200;
    img.height = 200;
    img.id = randomid;
    img.src = "./upload/Images/" + oFile.name;//i want to point to the file uploaded
    img.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById(container).appendChild(img);
    }
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

the above code is working but it is continuously updating the image. Is there another way to approach this issue?

Comment: Why do you need the second onchange event? You can invoke it by inserting it in the first function.

Comment: can you add html also?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should you promise or something like that. once you get the response from
the below function then only you should call the submit ().

```
 img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById(container).appendChild(img);
}
```

[May be this link will help you to understand event life cycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)